# Strange behaviour of the float type

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | double | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| az1        | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
| el1        | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
| az2        | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
| el2        | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
| rfs_angle  | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
| scan_speed | float  | YES  |     | 989898  |                |
+------------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I inserted this data more than 100times

```
INSERT INTO lidar_traj_table (az1, el1, az2, el2, rfs_angle, scan_speed)  VALUES (49.100, 0.000,989898,8.000,1.0,1.000)
```

When I'm trying to select the data I'm receiving nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM lidar_traj_table WHERE az1=49.1
```

When I'm selecting smaller data then 49.1 than I get all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM lidar_traj_table WHERE az1<=49.1
```

Why am I getting empty result for this:

```
SELECT * FROM lidar_traj_table WHERE az1=49.1
```

Comment: I think this is a problem with representing float by finite binary. See: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues), [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html). The last one may have a solution.

Comment: **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store exact values then you should use the `DECIMAL` data type instead of `FLOAT`.

Comment: Looks like a comment, but a powerful answer. +1 !!!